Getting ValidationException while trying to import 3DES 128 bit key in AWS Payment Cryptography
We have a specific requirement to store our 3DES 128bit key in AWS Payment Cryptography. Im using NodeJS SDK to do the needful, but getting validation error.

ERROR: ValidationException: KeyBlock data in the imported payload is invalid.

So, there are 3steps of implementation: 1. Get RSA public key. 2. Wrap my 3DES 128 bit key that I have. 3. Import the key in aws payment cryptography.
Error I'm getting is might be because of Step:2, I might be making some mistake in wrapping my key. I didn't get any help anywhere other than aws document only. I'm attaching documents that Im referring which might be useful.
Documentation that I'm referring to :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/payment-cryptography/command/ImportKeyCommand/
Any help will be most appreciated!!!!! THANK YOU!!!!
Code that I'm using to import key:
import { PaymentCryptographyClient, GetParametersForImportCommand, ImportKeyCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-payment-cryptography";
import crypto, { publicEncrypt} from "crypto"; // To wrap the key

const client = new PaymentCryptographyClient({
    region: "ap-southeast-1", credentials: {
        accessKeyId: "", // replace with your AWS Access Key ID
        secretAccessKey: "" // replace with your AWS Secret Access Key
    }
});

async function import3DESKey() {
    try {
        // Step 1: Get import parameters
        const getParamsInput = {
            KeyMaterialType: "KEY_CRYPTOGRAM",
            WrappingKeyAlgorithm: "RSA_2048" // Ensure this matches the actual wrapping algorithm
        };
        const getParamsCommand = new GetParametersForImportCommand(getParamsInput);
        const getParamsResponse = await client.send(getParamsCommand);
        console.log({ getParamsResponse });
        
        const { ImportToken, WrappingKeyCertificate } = getParamsResponse;

        // Step 2: Prepare key wrapping
        const threeDESKey = Buffer.from("404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F", "hex");

        // Decode the wrapping key certificate
        const wrappingCertPem = Buffer.from(WrappingKeyCertificate, "base64").toString("utf8");

        // Wrap the 3DES key using the RSA public key from the certificate
        const wrappedKey = publicEncrypt({
            key: wrappingCertPem,
            // padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING,// Double-check if OAEP or PKCS1 padding is expected by AWS
            padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING,// Double-check if OAEP or PKCS1 padding is expected by AWS
        }, threeDESKey);

        // Convert wrapped key to base64 format (AWS often expects base64)
        // const wrappedKeyBase64 = wrappedKey.toString("base64");

        // // Convert wrapped key to hex format
        const wrappedKeyHex = wrappedKey.toString("hex").toUpperCase();
       

        // Step 3: Import the wrapped key
        const importKeyInput = {
            KeyMaterial: {
                KeyCryptogram: {
                    KeyAttributes: {
                        KeyUsage: "TR31_D0_SYMMETRIC_DATA_ENCRYPTION_KEY",
                        KeyClass: "SYMMETRIC_KEY",
                        KeyAlgorithm: "TDES_2KEY",
                        KeyModesOfUse: {
                            NoRestrictions:true
                        },
                    },
                    Exportable: false, // Depending on your requirement
                    // WrappedKeyCryptogram: wrappedKeyBase64, // Hex format of the wrapped key
                    WrappedKeyCryptogram: wrappedKeyHex, // Hex format of the wrapped key
                    ImportToken: ImportToken,
                },
            },
            KeyCheckValueAlgorithm: "ANSI_X9_24", // Typically used for 3DES
            Enabled: true,
        };

        const importKeyCommand = new ImportKeyCommand(importKeyInput);
        const response = await client.send(importKeyCommand);
        console.log("Imported Key ARN:", response.Key.KeyArn);

    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error importing key:", error);
    }
}

import3DESKey();

Any help will be most appreciated!!!!! THANK YOU!!!!
